# How to get ControllerContext to build PDF using Rotativa in BackgroundJob with Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I have to send mails in my background application, for this I use *Hangfire*, but I have to attach a document to each mail with its recipient, the information of the document to be attached is in a table that I convert with rotativa.

My concern is when I want to convert the document into `byte[]` I always get that the `HttpContext` is `null`, obviously because there is no HTTP request which triggers the action while everything is in the background.

Here is my actual code:

```cs
var Avis_views = new ViewAsPdf("~/Views/AvisAutomatique/ExportPdfDebit.cshtml", printa)
{
    PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
    MinimumFontSize = 14,
    /*ageHeight=60,*/
    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
};

var fileName = "DEBITADVISE_" + Numcpt + "_" + _GetTransDateTime() + ".pdf";
//var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\DocumentPdf\", fileName);
byte[] abc =  Avis_views.BuildFile(quotesController.ControllerContext);
//System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, abc);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(abc);

sendemail(email, fileName, abc, emailc);
```

Can someone can help me initialize the httpcontext from my controller?

Comment: Why do you think you need an HttpContext at all? If this is a background process, there will be no HttpContext. Write your code in such a way that it's independent of HttpContext.

Comment: yes you are right in that case how to replace this line of code // byte[] abc =  Avis_views.BuildFile(quotesController.ControllerContext) // thks

Comment: I don't know what `Avis_views.BuildFile` does, or why it needs a controller context.

Comment: Avis_Views.Buildfile get the byte of the rotativa file, i just need to get the bytes of the file

Comment: So why does it need a controller context?

Comment: hello thanks boss, the ControllerContext is a parameter of the Buildfile(ControllerContext context), he need it to work

Comment: Why does Buildfile need a controller context? Do you see what I'm getting at with these questions?

Comment: it looks like an issue in Rotativa lib that it has to take a controller context, https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/pull/88

Comment: Please, take a look at this post, and the accepted answer. Is it helpful for your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508982/rotativa-controllercontext-is-null/63559614#63559614

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some week with trying with rotativa i fund another solution with Itextsharp bellow how i did:
1-first all installing the package ItextSharp and ItextSharp XMLWorker 
2- i designed my template in html page with the css put them in a 
folder(@"C:\Templates\Credit.html"; @"C:\Templates\pdfview.css";)
3-read the html and the css with this methode

```
public string RenderViewToString(string viewPath)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(viewPath);
        using (StreamReader streamReader = file.OpenText())
        {
            string viewLine = "";
            var result = string.Empty;
            while ((viewLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                result = result + viewLine;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and use this methode to convert to pdf:

```
 public byte[] GetPDF(string param1,string param2,etc...)
    {
        
        byte[] bPDF = null;
        try
        {
            pHTML = pHTML.Replace("{{parameter form the html file}}", param1);
            pHTML = pHTML.Replace("{{parameter form the html file}}", param2);
            
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML.ToString());

            
            var image = @"C:\Templates\avis.jpg";
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image);
            jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;
            jpg.ScaleToFit(50, 50);
            jpg.Alignment =iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
           

            
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(jpg);
            using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csstemp)))
            {
                using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pHTML)))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(oPdfWriter, doc, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                }
            }
            //htmlWorker.StartDocument();
            //// 5: parse the html into the document  
            //htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);

            //// 6: close the document and the worker  
            //htmlWorker.EndDocument();

            //htmlWorker.Close();
            doc.Close();

            bPDF = ms.ToArray();

            return bPDF;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var mess = ex.StackTrace;
            var mess2 = ex.Message;
        }

        return bPDF;


    }
```

Thanks your hope that will help someone

Comment: Hi, @Sylla. Glad to know it's working now. You could mark the answer for this response, as it seems it has finally solved you problem.

Comment: Please, follow the steps given in this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue in Rotativa lib that it has to take a controller context, github.com/webgio/Rotativa/pull/88

And you won't be able to pass the context to hangfire background process as you listed.

A work around (incase the file is not too big) might be that your hangfire process call a URL on your website which do the email sending code instead of doing the Rotativa and email sending in the hangfire background process.

Comment: hello Boss, the issue is that i'm passing a data model to the view and convert it with rotativa

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Rotativa and the owner of rotativa.io cloud service.

In the SaaS version of rotativa you can use the Nuget lib that will let you build PDFs from razor views without the need to reference Asp.net:

https://rotativa.io/site/blog/instructions/2020/07/31/create-pdf-in-net-core-without-aspnet.html

Comment: Thanks you Sir @Giorgio Bozio, im going to try it, and let know

Comment: Hello Sir @Giorgio Bozio, i used the RotativaHQ  and followed the tuto and its worked fine, im receiving the byte of the file, do i have full access of my file, will they block me as im using the free version thank you

Comment: Hello Sir @Giorgio , i want to add this, i have tried with httprequest like clicking to a link and call the action that works, but with background job calling the function doesn't works im receiving this error: Can't create controller context if no active HttpContext instance is available

Comment: H @Sylla are you folowing the instructions and using RotativaIO.NetCore?

Comment: hello Sir @Giorgio, im using Asp.net mvc that why i installed the HQ, or he can work even im not working with the asp.net core ???

Answer (score 0):

You can check cloud services as Giogio Bozio suggested, or, if you plan to use current Rotativa DLL, you could try the solution I suggested in my comment.

You code should look like this (embedded sample solution in the code you provided):

```
var Avis_views = new ViewAsPdf("~/Views/AvisAutomatique/ExportPdfDebit.cshtml", printa)
{
    PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
    MinimumFontSize = 14,
    /*ageHeight=60,*/
    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
};

var fileName = "DEBITADVISE_" + Numcpt + "_" + _GetTransDateTime() + ".pdf";
//var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\DocumentPdf\", fileName);

// Create an instance of your controller class (in example, I guess you are using mentioned quotesController)
QuotesController controllerInstance = new QuotesController();

// Generate RouteData based in your controller (even if you are not using on in this situation, you can reference an existent one)
RouteData route = new RouteData();
// Simply change "MyAction" and "QuotesController" for the name of real action name and controller, respectively
route.Values.Add("action", "MyAction");
route.Values.Add("controller", "QuotesController");

// Generate controller context, to use in the next step
ControllerContext newContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, controllerInstance);

byte[] abc =  Avis_views.BuildFile(newContext); // Here you send the generated controller context
//System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, abc);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(abc);

sendemail(email, fileName, abc, emailc);
```

Please, chek if it works for you, and don't forget to include the required references:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Dave Miller, i tried it but same issue, the httcontext still null

Comment: Hi @Sylla. You mean System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null, isn't it?

Comment: Yes @Dave Miller

Comment: Sorry @Sylla, can't attend this before. Then, the only chances I can see to achieve this are, on one hand, follow instructions to use RotativaHQ, as Giogio Bozio stated, and, on the other hand, create a web service that uses a MVC app with this logic (it's a bit tedious, but it's another workaround). I see you are opting for Rotativa SaaS version, so good luck with it!